# Would someone plese tell what section this is that I have outlined in red

Tags: nautilus

I am attempting to edit this theme and have no idea what this section is. So I outlined it in red and would appreciate someone telling me what section it is. thanks

[image]

The name of the section, I want the name of the section.

Comment: What theme? What section? Where?

Comment: Unclear, much?  We have no details of the "section" you're outlining.  New users can't add images, so if you put the link to the image in the post someone with edit privs can edit in the picture

Comment: We don't know the "name of the section" unless you show us what section you have outlined.  We have no images from you for this, or anything else to identify the specific section that you're looking at.

Comment: Menu bar? IMO is the same for all windows, even those in Windows has it.

Answer (score 2):

I am almost sure that is a [**menu bar**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_bar):

> A **menu bar** is a region of a screen or application interface where drop down menus are displayed. The menu bar's purpose is to supply a common housing for window- or application-specific menus which provide access to such functions as opening files, interacting with an application, or displaying help documentation or manuals. Menu bars are typically present in graphical user interfaces that display documents and representations of files in windows and windowing systems but menus can be used as well in command line interface programs like text editors or filemanagers where drop-down menu is activated with shortcut key or combination.

More about: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_bar